# Getting errors when trying to compile qt-labs-qt3d in windows with visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, compiler-errors

Hi
i followed the instructions from the sites using Qt 4.7.3 compiled from source :
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3d-snapshot/qt3d-building.html
and
http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/03/compiling-qt3d-for-windows
but when compiling the qt3d im getting this error:

```
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(263) : error C2039: 'Options' : is not a member of 'QDeclarativePixmap'
        d:\cpp\qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\include\qtdeclarative\private\../../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativepixmapcache_p.h(59) : see declaration of 'QDeclarativePixmap'
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(263) : error C2065: 'Options' : undeclared identifier
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(263) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'options'
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(263) : error C2065: 'options' : undeclared identifier
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(263) : error C2039: 'Cache' : is not a member of 'QDeclarativePixmap'
        d:\cpp\qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\include\qtdeclarative\private\../../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativepixmapcache_p.h(59) : see declaration of 'QDeclarativePixmap'
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(263) : error C2065: 'Cache' : undeclared identifier
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(265) : error C2065: 'options' : undeclared identifier
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(265) : error C2039: 'Asynchronous' : is not a member of 'QDeclarativePixmap'
        d:\cpp\qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3\include\qtdeclarative\private\../../../src/declarative/util/qdeclarativepixmapcache_p.h(59) : see declaration of 'QDeclarativePixmap'
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(265) : error C2065: 'Asynchronous' : undeclared identifier
.\qdeclarativeeffect.cpp(266) : error C2065: 'options' : undeclared identifier
qdeclarativemesh.cpp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was indeed a known issue for 4.7.2 and has been fixed:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17872